# Class within hover CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I would like to switch images from an sprite map when using hover. The images are classes. So far I have

(I have multiple images all with a hover image.)

```
.contact-icon, .contact-icon-2, .help-icon, .help-icon-2{
background: url(sprites.png) no-repeat;}
```

-positioning for first image

```
.contact-icon{
background-position: 0 -77px ;
width: 66px;
height: 66px;}
```

-

```
.contact-icon:hover, .contact-icon:active{
    .contact-icon-2{
    background-position: -95px -75px ;
    width: 66px; 
    height: 66px;
  }
}
```

Or

```
.contact-icon:hover, .contact-icon:active ~ .contact-icon-2{
    background-position: -95px -75px ;
    width: 66px; 
    height: 66px;
}
```

Should I first declare positioning for the second image and then write a css code for hover with just the class inside? Or can I just style the class within the hover class?

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: Little difficult to understand your requirement but you should not repeat the common properties of css in each icon or in hover/ active stage.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class having common properties of icons like :

```
.sprite { 
  background: url(sprites.png) no-repeat; 
  width: 66px; 
  height: 66px; 
  display:inline-block;
}
```

then create unique classes for each of your icon :

```
.contact-icon{
  background-position: 0 -77px ;
}
```

then `hover` actions for each :

```
.contact-icon:hover{
  background-position: -95px -75px ;
}
```

use it like this in your html:

```
<a href="#" class="sprite contact-icon"></a>
```